# How to edit a multiline pattern in bash (sed and awk are available)

Tags: bash, regex, sed, awk

So here is my very specific task. I have patterns of type

```
.*[class|namespace|struct].*
```

(this is one part of the pattern, to be precise),

then an arbitrary amount of newlines `\n` or spaces  intermixed (may be 0 newlines, but at least 1 space), and right after that I have a very specific pattern - I basically know that this line always comes in the way of

```
{specific_text;^
```

This was the second part of the pattern. That is it.

Notes: if there is part one of the pattern, then there definitely exists part 2.

The task

I need to replace each line with custom text that comes right before the corresponding part one pattern, into single curly brace and a newline symbol, like this - ''{\n''.

How do I do it with a bash shell, awk and sed?

Note. So you can see that basically I want to change the first line that matches my very specific pattern, AND which is the first among its kind after the class|namespace|struct keyword.

Example.

```
class A { specific_text;
```

is transformed into

```
class A {
```

And this

```
class A

{ specific_text;
```

becomes

```
class A

{
```

Please note in the last example we preserved the newlines.

Comment: Could you give an example of input text and expected result?

Comment: If a perl oneliner is an option for you, you can use: `perl -0777 -ape 's/class \w+\s+{\K specific_text//` inputfile >outputfile

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have perl at my disposal, well but I think that is possible with perl regex right?

Comment: Perl regex will work (with perl), but I don't know how to transpose this regex for use with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/class\|namespace\|struct/ {
   : loop
   s/{ *specific_text;$/{/
   t
   n
   b loop
   }'
```

It works like this:

- Until `class` or `namespace` or `struct` is found, `sed` does nothing more than its default action: it prints incoming lines as they are.
- When `class` or `namespace` or `struct` is found, `sed` enters a loop.
- `: loop` is a label, the beginning of the loop.
- `b loop` branches to the label, it's the end of the loop.
- There are two ways to leave the loop:

  - end of input,
  - `t` which branches to the end of the script.
- `t` will only work if the preceding `s` is successful.
- If `t` doesn't work, the script continues to `n` which prints the current line and moves to the next.

In other words both the outside and the inside of the loop print incoming lines, except only in the loop we are trying to do the substitution with `s`. A successful substitution leaves the loop. The tool will loop again if another `class` or `namespace` or `struct` is encountered.

In yet other words this is exactly what you want (I think):

> to change the first line that matches my very specific pattern, AND which is the first among its kind after the class|namespace|struct keyword.

Notes:

- The script doesn't care what is between `class` (or `namespace` or `struct`) and the specific pattern.
- I adjusted your patterns. In particular
- I allowed spaces between `{` and `specific_text` because your test cases have spaces;
- I used `$` instead of `^`, because `^` in your pattern is literal, it makes no sense (maybe you confused `^` and `$` anchors).

---

Example input:

```
foo
bar
class A {      specific_text;
baz { specific_text;
qux
this is my namespace

whatever
abc {specific_text;
foo
{ specific_text;
{specific_text;
```

The output:

```
foo
bar
class A {
baz { specific_text;
qux
this is my namespace

whatever
abc {
foo
{ specific_text;
{specific_text;
```

Altered lines:

- `class A {      specific_text;`
- `abc {specific_text;` (because of `namespace` few lines before)

Comment: Works like a charm. Yes your adjustments are what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: How do I modify it to start a new cycle instead of jumping to the end of script on match? I may have multiple occurrences of patterns

Comment: @ArtemHevorhian Do you mean "multiple in a line" or "multiple after `class`"? Probably the latter. If the latter then is it true that the first `class` (or `namespace` or ...) should enable the "substitution mode" once and for all? If not then *what exactly* should disable it? In my current code a successful substitution disables it, but it seems this is not what you want now.

Comment: @ArtemHevorhian If I read the documentation right, after `sed` gets to the end of the script, it *does* start a new cycle (for the next input line). Therefore "start a new cycle instead of jumping to the end of script" needs to be clarified. Jumping to the end does start a new cycle. For now I can only guess what you want and my previous comment is based on guesses really.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I did not check it before commenting, I mean I have a "class" keyword and then "specific_text" after it, then again a "class" and "specific_text" after it, and so on; and your script works as expected - it fixes every occurrence; Yep now that u clarified that Jumping to the end does start a new cycle, that seems natural, thanks