# How to substitute every opening curly brace that changes bracket balance from 0 to 1 with sed/awk?

Tags: bash, regex, sed, awk

Example input:

```
void C::foo()
{ // <- this changes bracket balance from 0 to 1
    if (true)
    { // balance is 2 after we process this bracket
       ...
    } // now it is 1 again
} // now bracket balance is zero again, so next opening brace will be 
  // subsituted
```

Output

```
void C::foo()
{ PROCESSED;
    if (true)
    { 
        ...
    } 
}
```

I have sed and awk at my disposal. Currently I know how to do the substitution in a very generic way thanks to the answer here [How to edit a multiline pattern in bash (sed and awk are available)](https://superuser.com/questions/1536112/how-to-edit-a-multiline-pattern-in-bash-sed-and-awk-are-available), but I do not know how to catch the described curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F "" '{
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if ($i == "}" && count > 0) count--
      if ($i == "{" ) if (count++ == 0) $i="{ PROCESSED;"
      printf "%s", $i
      }
   printf "%s", ORS
   }'
```

I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564186/10765659) to parse each line character by character.

Notes:

- The logic does not allow `count` to reach negative values.
- `(count++ == 0)` increases the `count` after comparing to `0`.
- `ORS` is the output record separator, by default a newline.
- The code *doesn't care* about quoting, escaping, comments etc.